# BottomNavigationView set optionselected with ViewPager Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-viewpager, bottomnavigationview

I am building a App Where I use A BottomNavigationView and display the fragments with a ViewPager.

When I push or touch the buttoms of the Bottom Navigation, I dont have problems, the fragment displays correctly in the viewpager.

The problem is that I can slide just the viewPager and when I do it, the bottom navigation does not change to the correct option.

I saw that I need to add **ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener** and create three methods for manage the view pager, but I dont now How to set the BottomNavigation item selected when the user slide the viewpager
For example, I touch the buttom 4 of the BottomNavigationBar and I saw Automatically the fragment 4 in the view pager(where I display the text "Fragment4"),,, and then I slide the ViewPager until the Fragment1, but the BottomNavigation is the option4 still selected,, it does not change when I slide the viewpager u.u

I hope you can help me, thanks

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener
{

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        bottomNavigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigation.NavigationItemSelected += Navigation_NavigationItemSelected;

        SupportToolbar toolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SupportActionbar actionBar = SupportActionBar;
        actionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu);
        actionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawerLayout);

        NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null)
        {
            setUpDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

        //TabLayout tabs = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);

        viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        setUpViewPager(viewPager);

        //tabs.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }

    private void Navigation_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.navigation_myState:
                viewPager.SetCurrentItem(0, false);
                break;
            case Resource.Id.navigation_study:
                viewPager.SetCurrentItem(1, false);
                break;
            case Resource.Id.navigation_flashcards:
                viewPager.SetCurrentItem(2, false);
                break;
            case Resource.Id.navigation_test:
                viewPager.SetCurrentItem(3, false); ;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
    {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
        adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment1(), "Fragment1");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment2(), "Fragment2");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment3(), "Fragment3");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment4(), "Fragment4");

        viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                drawerLayout.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
                return true;

            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }

    private void setUpDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e) =>
         {
             e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
             drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
         };
    }


    public class ViewPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public List<SupportFragment> Fragments { get; set; }
        public List<string> FragmentsNames { get; set; }

        public ViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager FragManager) : base (FragManager)
        {
            Fragments = new List<SupportFragment>();
            FragmentsNames = new List<string>();
        }

        public void AddFragment(SupportFragment fragment, string name)
        {
            Fragments.Add(fragment);
            FragmentsNames.Add(name);
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return Fragments.Count;
            }
        }

        public override SupportFragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return Fragments[position];
        }

        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(FragmentsNames[position]);
        }
    }





    public void OnPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnPageSelected(int position)
    {
        //I think that here I need to put something like bottomNavigatin.setItemselecte(position) or (bottomNavigation.something(Resource.Id.navigation_flashcards) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to hookup the `ViewPager.PageSelected` to `BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelected`. Here's how you can do it

```
void ViewPager_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e) 
{
     var item = _navigationView.Menu.GetItem(e.Position);
     _navigationView.SelectedItemId = item.ItemId; 
} 

void NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e) 
{
     _viewPager.SetCurrentItem(e.Item.Order, true); 
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Checkout the full implementation in my post here: https://intelliabb.com/2017/12/02/tutorial-bottomnavigationview-and-viewpager-in-xamarin-android/